# Rename a namespace from an external npm package in typescript

Tags: typescript, namespaces, arcgis-js-api, type-declaration

I am working alot with the ArcGIS JS API in typescript, using their [@arcgis/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@arcgis/core) ES6 modules.  In that package, they export a namespace:

```
// @arcgis/core/interface.d.ts

declare namespace __esri {
  // a LOT of classes, functions, properties, etc
  ...
}
```

In my files, I can reference things like `__esri.FeatureLayerProperties`, or `__esri.GroupLayer`, or whatever.  Its silly, but I hate the namespace `__esri`, and I'd love to just rename it myself to `esri` in my own `.d.ts` file.

I've looked at a number of questions tangentially related to this, but nothing so specific and simple as renaming a namespace from an external npm package, without having to manually specify everything that's in the namespace.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few alternative approaches you might consider:

Approach 1: Import and Re-export the Namespace
You can try importing the __esri namespace into your declaration file and then re-export it. However, this might not work depending on how the ArcGIS library exports its types.

```
// arcgis-core-augmentation.d.ts
import * as __esri from '@arcgis/core';

declare global {
  export namespace esri {
    export import FeatureLayerProperties = 
__esri.FeatureLayerProperties;
    export import GroupLayer = __esri.GroupLayer;
    // ... and so on for other types you need
  }
}
```

Approach 2: Global Augmentation
Another way is to use global augmentation, but this requires explicitly specifying the types you want to re-export.

```
// arcgis-core-augmentation.d.ts
declare global {
  namespace esri {
    type FeatureLayerProperties = __esri.FeatureLayerProperties;
    type GroupLayer = __esri.GroupLayer;
    // ... and so on for other types you need
  }
}
```

Approach 3: Use Type Aliases in Your Code
Instead of trying to rename the namespace globally, you can create type aliases in the files where you use these types.

```
type FeatureLayerProperties = __esri.FeatureLayerProperties;
type GroupLayer = __esri.GroupLayer;
```

Comment: When I try this, in the custom .d.ts file, I get `Cannot find name '__esri'.ts(2304)`.  TS version is 5.2.2

Comment: Thank you for the update....none of thee options exactly hits the mark.  I don't want to have to manually redeclare every member of the namespace I want to use.  That's a huge pain, there are thousands of items in there.  I just want to basically reexport the existing namespace, with all its members, under a new name.  Simple, but complex.